# one database or many to make it more efficient?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to know if it is more or less efficient to have multiple databases with an index of databases relative to each dataset.

I do not know to what extent multicache can adversely affect performance.

Suppose 10 bases in 2GB data each rather than a single 20GB.

For example: the data of userid 293484 are in third database.

Thanks.

Comment: Look for Partitioning instead of multi tenancy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)

Comment: If you _have_ to go this route, look at using [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html), but you should establish through careful profiling whether you have a problem at all. At present, any comments are little more than guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a common technique known as sharding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29

Answer (score 1):

Altimately the code you will have to write to maintain such a structure will kill you.

Keep it simple, keep it in one database, and use proper design patterns and indexing.

Database engines are design to deal with large amounts of data, so if your hadrware is sufficient, your queries well structured and the design good, you should not have to many performance problems.

Comment: I only care about efficiency, not so much the need to write code. The coffee is not as expensive. I know are "ready to deal", but I care only the practical fact.